# Android Toast not showing when cancelling a previous one

Tags: android, android-context, toast, applicationcontext, android-toast

I have a `ToastUtil` singleton that shows a toast and it cancels a previous toast if already shown on screen. Here's my current code:

```
object ToastUtil {

    private lateinit var mToast: Toast

    fun init(applicationContext: Context) {
        mToast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    }

    fun showShortToast(message: String) {
        mToast.cancel()
        mToast.setText(message)
        mToast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        mToast.show()
    }

    fun showShortToast(messageId: Int) {
        mToast.cancel()
        mToast.setText(messageId)
        mToast.duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        mToast.show()
    }
}
```

But the Toast messages aren't showing up on the phone. The `ToastUtil` has definitely been initialized (`init(applicationContext`) in my custom `App` implementation:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        ToastUtil.init(this)
    }
}
```

I have tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/33878500/8434188 with no avail. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Any chance you're trying to show the Toast from a background thread?

Comment: Yea, i tried to `runOnUIThread` and it's not working either. I got a solution though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is now working and Toasts are showing up. It's also *cleaner* in a way as I do not have to initialize it in my app implementation.

```
object ToastUtil {

    private var mToast: Toast? = null

    fun Context.showShortToast(message: String) {
        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast!!.cancel()
        }
        mToast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        mToast?.show()
    }

    fun Context.showShortToast(
        messageId: Int,
        vararg strings: String = arrayOf()
    ) {
        this.showShortToast(getString(messageId, strings))
    }
}
```